# Software Center is Crashed

Tags: software-center

I've installed a Ubuntu 12.04 with Windows 7.
At the very beginning it worked perfectly and raised no problems.
I installed the 3rd party updates also while installing the OS.
So the MP3 and videos are working perfectly.

But a day later, a big core problem is raised on my system.
If I opened the Ubuntu Software-Center, it just opens and the animated wheel turns for a couple of second and suddenly it closes.

Likewise, all the LibreOffice applications are seeming so. When I open them, it just opens and welcome screen stands for a couple of seconds and suddenly closes.

I tried to overcome these issues by using these codes.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

And tried many codes. But nothing responds.

Hope my packages are crashed.
So please anyone help me to overcome this issue
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Tried rebooting into recovery and clicking fix filesystem that usually does the job for me.
If not try reinstalling ubuntu if you want to backup your apps to a flash drive and reinstall in your fresh install.
Do this `cd /var/cache/apt/archives`
Than `sudo cp *.deb /home/user/apps`
Than copy that apps file to your flash drive or burn it to a cd.
Than reinstall ubuntu etc than cd into your apps directory and run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`